# Moving uiimageview created programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I wrote the following code and it does not work. Picture appears but I can not move it

```
UIImageView *oneselement = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
oneselement = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1el.png"]];
oneselement.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 122, 122);
[self.view addSubview:oneselement];


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if([touch view]==oneselement)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        oneselement.center=location;
    }}
```

I added a picture to view and wrote the following code

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *oneEl;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *oneEl;
```

.m

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if([touch view]==oneEl)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        oneEl.center=location;
    }
}
```

And it works!
How can I make so that programmatically created by uiimageview could move?

**NSMUTABLEARRAY**

```
self.elements=[myElements getElements];

imagesElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(ElemetsList *item in self.elements)
{
        UIImageView *oneelement = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:item.imgElement]];
        oneelement.frame = CGRectMake(item.positionX, item.positionY, item.width, item.height);
        oneelement.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        [imagesElements addObject:oneelement];
}

for(UIImageView *img in imagesElements) 
    [self.view addSubview:img];

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    for(UIImageView *img in imagesElements) 
    {  
        if([self view] == img)
        {
            CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
            img.center=location;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to move image or rotate image?

Comment: you have a memory leak in your code, u should release oneelement after  it has been added to array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize your UIImageView like the following code and then it will  work like your second example:

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIImageView *oneselement;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *oneselement;
```

ViewController.m

```
//initialize your UIImageView
UIImageView *newOneselement = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1el.png"]];
self.oneselement = newOneselement;
self.oneselement.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.oneselement.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 122, 122);
[self.view addSubview:self.oneselement];
[newOneselement release];

//Handle touchesMoved
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if([touch view]==self.oneselement)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        self.oneselement.center=location;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! It is necessary to oneselement was not. H. Programmatically create a picture.

Comment: add one code line where you initialize UIImageView: self.oneselement.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Comment: why not, you can create an array and put your uiimageviews inside

Comment: Please see the first message I tried to do so but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Please see [**this**](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/move-an-image-with-animation.html) link.
You can also try :

In order to move an image, you should enclose the code to move in an animation block:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
tapImage.center = CGPointMake(156, 110);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

You can also create a method to execute upon completion of the animation with the UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: method.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animateImages)];
tapImage.center = CGPointMake(156, 110);
[UIView commitAnimations];

//other stuff

-(void)animateImages{
     [tapImage startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: Hello! A little is needed to move the image with your finger.