# how to drag dynamically created UIImageview in obj c (xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, drag-and-drop, uiimageview

i have gone through the many tutorials to drag an image on screen using touchesmoved method
but most of them are not for dynamically created imageviews

in my project i created 5 UIImageview programatically,

now i want that user can drag them on screen>> i also follow this answer
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541130/moving-uiimageview-created-programmatically) but all in vain , no success so far>

the code for creating the dynamically imageview is

```
for (int i = 0; i < index ; i++) 
{
UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
[UIImageimageNamed:image_name]];        
self.imageView1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
imageView1.frame = CGRectMake(xvalue, yvalue, 80.0f, 80.0f);
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:imageView1];
}
```

Thanks in advance for good replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused with how you are creating UIImageViews because you are using a for-loop but a static name. So you might have 15 UIImageViews with the name "imageView1".
But anyways, this shouldn't matter at all if you are using the code in the question you linked to. Perhaps you put the lines in out of order... this is the proper order. (If it doesn't work let me know, along with the errors you get)

```
//-(void)ViewDidLoad? {???? is this your function??
    int xvalue = 0;//?? not sure where you declared these
    int yvalue = 0;//?? not sure where you declared these
    for (int i = 0; i < index ; i++) {
        UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
        [UIImageimageNamed:image_name]];        
        self.imageView1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        imageView1.frame = CGRectMake(xvalue, yvalue, 80.0f, 80.0f);
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:imageView1];
    }

    self.elements=[myElements getElements];
    imagesElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(ElemetsList *item in self.elements) {
            UIImageView *oneelement = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:item.imgElement]];
            oneelement.frame = CGRectMake(item.positionX, item.positionY, item.width, item.height);
            oneelement.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            [imagesElements addObject:oneelement];
    }

    for(UIImageView *img in imagesElements) {
        [self.view addSubview:img];
    }
//}? End Function, whatever it may be...?

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    for(UIImageView *img in imagesElements) 
    {  
        if([self view] == img)
        {
            CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
            img.center=location;
        }
    }
}
```

If you just want to hard-code in the moving for one image try this:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    imageView1.center=[touch locationInView:self.view];
}
```

Comment: i have tried the above corrected code>>only the lines inside the for loop >> but not worked yet

Comment: You only tried the code inside `for (int i = 0; i < index ; i++) {` ?

Comment: i have already used the touchesmoved method but the program couldn't goes to the desired activity >>
tell me the purpose of self.elements code and where to add this???

Comment: This elements code let's Xcode detect what you are dragging over and if it's an image it lets you drag that image. If you don't want to have all of that elements code (which should go inside whatever function you have your for-loop in for creating the images) than you need to hard-code in the touchesMoved code, although I don't think that is a good idea since you are creating multiple images with the same name... (Look into using tags if you decide to hard-code)

Comment: I've edited my answer, try using the touches moved code that I aded **Below** my original code.

Comment: i have tried without the self.elements code and its giving me the error about the unrecognized selector send on ViewLoad method> means the code within the for loop is not working for me>> and the line with is causing trouble is 
        self.imageView1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
any guides to this

Comment: Just use this, `imageView1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` drop the "self." it's not a property since it's locally defined.

Comment: Also the code you tried without the self.elements, was it the new code I just posted _BELOW_ the original code in a separate code block? Or was it the original code I got from the other question you linked to?

Comment: the question i linked didnot worked for me>>
in my project i have added the for loop for creating the iageview and then i put the the touches moved function for drag an image>> as far as elements are concern i have try that because of the fact that are not too convincing for me>>
and now i am trying this but its giving me the error>> any suggestion how i use it my program >>\

Comment: You edited your comment after I posted that? Haha>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Comment: My suggestion for getting rid of that error, like I stated above, would be to remove the "self." have you tried this? Also which TouchesMoved code are you using, this is the question I want answered haha, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No, you don't have to use the elements variable if you would let me know which touchesMoved method you are using that would help me determine how to help you. This is my third and last time asking. I don't know why you are so stuck on the elements variable, if you don't' want to use it, fine, if you do want to use it stick it above your for-loop (like in the example code) but regardless of that, let me know which tochesMoved you are using.

Comment: -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    imageView1.center=[touch locationInView:self.view];
}
this is the touch method i used hard coded but not working

Comment: sorry for that confusion>>

Comment: Thankyou :) You should only need that and your for-loop, if the code is still not working can you tell me where you are getting errors, did your remove the "self." from all of the "imageView1" in your for-loop?

Comment: UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
[UIImage imageNamed:image_name]];     

  imageView1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


        imageView1.frame = CGRectMake(xvalue, yvalue, 80.0f, 80.0f);
        
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        
[self.view addSubview:imageView1];

  
this is my code within the for loop 
and nothinhs is working 
tell me where should i remove the self keyword >>
the above code doesnot gives the error but image drag is not working

Comment: waiting for the reply @albert Renshaw

Comment: I don't know what could be possible going wrong except maybe your for-loop is constantly being called which is constantly re-setting the imageView's x and y position... where is your for-loop located? Inside viewDidLoad? Why do you have a for-loop, try running the code with the for-loop commented out but all of the code inside of it not commented out.

Comment: the also try that >> but no success>> and the for loop is located in read()method and then read method is called in the viewdidload>>

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you... I don't know what's wrong or how to communicate what's wrong... I suggest watching some video tutorials on touchesMoved via youtube before trying to move to the next step in coding this app. Good luck!

Comment: :: thanks the problem is solved the only things that i doing wrong is the release statement for that :: other than that all code is fine and now working :: thanks for this long conversation>> your suggestion definitely help me >>

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to address this issue. You can add UIPanGestureRecognizer to each UIImageView at the time its creation, or you can use touchesBegan:, touchesMoved: on self (assuming it's a UIViewController) and traverse each UIImageView to see if its frame contains the point of the touch.